Find two permutation matrices $P,Q$, such that$M^{T}=PMQ$
Let $M$ be an $n\times n$ $\{0,1\}$-matrix with exactly $m$ ones in each row and column, can we find two permutation matrices $P,Q$, such that$M^{T}=PMQ$?
Use this,we can get that the above is true for $m=2$.

how do you prove it for $m=2$?

@Exodd $M=M_1+M_2$, notice that $M_1^{T}(M_1+M_2)M_2^{T}=M_2^{T}+M_1^{T}=M^{T}$
